# GAE JSP and Facebook-api-java iframe fb_sig_* param

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, facebook, http-headers

I am building facebook app using iFrame (using Google App Engine Java,JSP and Facebook-api-java), and when Facebook calls back to my website, I expect to get the fb_sig_* request params for the iFrame, but I get those params in HTTP referer header instead.

When I use the php client, i get the fb_sig_* in the $[_GET] as expected.

What have I done wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get them in the referrer, then it means that a redirect has taken place. If this is not the expected behaviour by Facebook, then you need to ensure that you don't have some `Servlet` or `Filter` in the request chain which redirects requests using `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()` for some reason.

Comment: thanks! i got the fb_sig* on the callback page, but then I click on another link without passing on the params..